# Postfix/Dovecot multiple authentication against Active Directory

Tags: centos, active-directory, postfix, authentication, dovecot

So I have working mail server which authenticates against active directory. Everything works fine until I try to add a secondary authentication backend..

**Server info:**

```
Server OS: CentOS 7.1.1503
Postfix version: 2.10.1
Dovecot version: 2.2.10
```

At the moment mine configuration looks like this:

**Postfix Configuration files:**

/etc/postfix/main.cf

```
virtual_mailbox_base = /homes/vmail/homes 
virtual_mailbox_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-users-primary.cf 
virtual_alias_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-groups-primary.cf
virtual_uid_maps = static:989 
virtual_gid_maps = static:987
```

ldap-users-primary.cf

```
server_host = 192.168.250.200
search_base = cn=Users, dc=domain, dc=local
version = 3
query_filter = (&(objectclass=person)(mail=%s))
result_attribute = samaccountname
result_format = %s/
bind = yes
bind_dn = user@domain.local
bind_pw = password
```

ldap-groups-primary.cf

```
server_host = 192.168.250.200
search_base = ou=Email_Groups, dc=domain,dc=local
version = 3
query_filter = (&(objectclass=group)(mail=%s))
leaf_result_attribute = mail
special_result_attribute = member
bind = yes
bind_dn = user@domain.local
bind_pw = password
start_tls = no
```

**Dovecot configuration files:**

/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-auth.conf

```
passdb {
driver = ldap
args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap-primary.conf
}

userdb {
driver = static
args = uid=989 gid=987 home=/homes/vmail/homes/%u
}
```

dovecot-ldap-primary.conf

```
hosts = 192.168.250.200
base = cn=Users, dc=domain, dc=local
ldap_version = 3
auth_bind = yes
auth_bind_userdn = domain\%u
```

All the above setup is working fine and doesn't cause any problems. Until I try to add secondary domain controller..

To do that I have created new configuration files: ldap-users-secondary.cf,  ldap-groups-secondary.cf, dovecot-ldap-secondary.conf.

The only thing that is different in those files are and IP address of server (it just points to secondary domain controller). If I use those files alone everything works just fine. But if I modify /etc/postfix/main.cf like this:

```
virtual_mailbox_base = /homes/vmail/homes 
virtual_mailbox_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-users-primary.cf, ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-users-secondary.cf
virtual_alias_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-groups-primary.cf, ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-groups-secondary.cf
virtual_uid_maps = static:989 
virtual_gid_maps = static:987
```

And /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-auth.conf

```
passdb {
driver = ldap
args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap-primary.conf
}

passdb {
driver = ldap
args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap-secondary.conf
}

userdb {
driver = static
args = uid=989 gid=987 home=/homes/vmail/homes/%u
}
```

It just stops working and starts giving out these errors:

```
NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 451 4.3.0 <user@domain.local>: Temporary lookup failure;
```

Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: So this is a secondary controller of the same domain, am I right? So why don't you just put a DNS name instead of IP address? This way you're gonna provide redundancy without introducing another config file.

Comment: Yes, you're right... And probably this is going to fix this issue since in this case DNS will take care of which server is getting requests.. Feeling a bit stupid tho that I didn't came up with such a simple solution. Going to test it later to see if it works as it should.

Comment: i'm sorry, but there are arguments against just using dns as a crutch here. the original question is much more interesting. why does postfix not allow multiple ldap sources? at least dovecot allows multiple ldap hosts in a config file. DNS round-robin'ing actually will just hand out the ip of the dead LDAP server 1/number-of-servers of the time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution was pretty simple.. Just as @sam_pan_mariusz sugested instead of IP address I've putted DNS name. Runned some testing and everything works as it should.

Comment: this is more of a bad work-around than a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Postfix and Dovecot both allow failover with multiple ldap hosts in the ldap configs. As far as I can tell, though, the configs have to be the same on all the LDAP servers. At least for postfix.

On Postfix, this does NOT work reliably :

```
virtual_mailbox_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ad-users-dc-1.cf, ldap:/etc/postfix/ad-users-dc-2.cf
```

This does work. In main.cf :

```
virtual_mailbox_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ad-users.cf
```

... and in the ad-users.cf file :

```
server_host     = 192.168.44.75,192.168.44.76
server_port     = 389
version         = ...
bind            = ...
start_tls       = ...
bind_dn         = CN=...
bind_pw         = ...
... etc
```

In Dovecot, this works. In your ldap target config file :

```
hosts   = 192.168.44.75:389, 192.168.44.76:389
```